# Python - Selenium - Webscrape Table

Tags: python, xslt, selenium, xpath, python-3.x

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from tkinter import StringVar, messagebox, Entry, Tk

chromeOps=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOps._binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
chromeOps._arguments = ["--enable-internal-flash"]

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe", port=4445, chrome_options=chromeOps)
time.sleep(3)

browser.get('website')
elem=browser.find_element_by_id('MainForm')
eli=elem.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ReportHolder"]')
```

Now beyond this point is a:

table xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" width="100%"

Now, I've noticed that this prevents me from xpath'ing directly to the table contents.

So my question is:
How do I interact or extract the contents of this table?

EDIT:
Attempting to access the xpath of the table or its contents throw a 'noSuchElementException', the line of code that does this is:

```
eli=elem.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ReportHolder"]/table')
```

(note: I can't give exact html access as it's a companies password protected location.)

Has anyone encounter a similar problem?  Or can anyone notice something improper about the xpath (even though it was a direct copy inspection).

EDIT2:
Simplified example XHTML extracted from 
http://s1362.photobucket.com/user/superempl/media/roady2_zps3e1430d2.png.html

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>XPath</title>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="MainForm" method="post" action="hidden" id="MainForm">
            <div id="ReportHolder">
                <table xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" width="100%">
                    <tr><td></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: pls add relevant html part in your question

Comment: How does it prevent you from using XPath? I don't see why it would.

Comment: If you cannot provide the full document, provide an example _which fails for your code_. The question cannot be answered as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using thread sleep, you should use the wait class. I have not written webdriver in python, but it should be something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPath, '//*[@id="ReportHolder"]/table/tbody/tr')))
```

The webdriverwait `presence_of_element_located` will return you the element once it is present in DOM and then you can interact with it.

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple.  It's a timing issue.

Solution:  Place a time.sleep(5) before the xpath request.

```
browser.get('http://www.mmgt.co.uk/HTMLReport.aspx?ReportName=Fleet%20Day%20Summary%20Report&ReportType=7&CategoryID=4923&Startdate='+strDate+'&email=false')
time.sleep(5)
ex=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ReportHolder"]/table/tbody/tr/td')
```

xpath is requesting a reference to dynamic content.

The table is dynamic content and takes longer to load that content then it does for the python program to reach line:

```
ex=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ReportHolder"]/table/tbody/tr')
```

from its previous line of:

```
browser.get('http://www.mmgt.co.uk/HTMLReport.aspx?ReportName=Fleet%20Day%20Summary%20Report&ReportType=7&CategoryID=4923&Startdate='+strDate+'&email=false')
```

Comment: i will downvote every answer that suggest any form of thread sleep.

Comment: What happens if your element takes 5.01 sec to be present? Or if it takes 4sec, then you are simply wasting time.